# Random walk on turtle graphics pause/resume function

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Rookie here!
I modified a random walk assignment from an online course I'm taking, and I'm trying to make a function that will pause the program and when called again will resume it.
It currently pauses, but I can't seem to make it resume; or to be precise, once it's paused I can't get any reaction - as if the screen stopped listening for events.

I already tried:

- Creating a separate function for resume - The function works if I call it before I pause but after it pauses I can't call it
- I could add an else clause for the if go condition where I declare a variable as screen.textinput and according the input the program will either resume or end, but I want it to be as simple as pausing.
- I tried adding a screen.listen() call after the if go breaks as an else clause but it doesn't seem to work...
- I tried setting go=False as default and then starting it by calling a function to set it to True, but that too doesn't work.

P.S:
I'm new to programming so if you have further remarks and advice I'd truly appreciate it.

Thanks a lot!

attaching my code with comments in relevant lines:

```
from turtle import Turtle, colormode, Screen
from random import choice, randint

colormode(255)
tim = Turtle('circle')
tim.speed('fastest')
tim.width(10)
screen = Screen()
go = True  # Boolean to initialize line 31


def pause():  # Currently it pauses, but doesn't resume.
    """Pause the program by setting go to False, and resume it if it was paused"""
    global go
    if go:
        go = False
    else:
        go = True


def random_color():
    """Return a random color"""
    r = randint(0, 255)
    g = randint(0, 255)
    b = randint(0, 255)
    generated_color = (r, g, b)
    return generated_color


screen.listen()  # Starts listening for events
screen.onkey(fun=pause, key='p')  # Event - when the 'p' key is pressed, the 'pause' function is called.

while True:  # Outer loop to prevent the code from ending when 'go' is set to False by pressing 'p' the first time
    if go:  # As default is True, after pausing can't restart it...
        if 200 > tim.xcor() > -200 and 200 > tim.ycor() > -200:
            tim.color(random_color())
            tim.forward(choice(range(50)))
            tim.setheading(choice(range(360)))
        else:
            tim.goto(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in your implementation, when `go` is `False`, there is no function running to get the keyboard events (since you are not running the main event loop). A non-elegant way of fixing it is to add a dummy action when `go == False`. Change your final loop to this:

```py
while True:  # Outer loop to prevent the code from ending when 'go' is set to False by pressing 'p' the first time
    if go:  # As default is True, after pausing can't restart it...
        if 200 > tim.xcor() > -200 and 200 > tim.ycor() > -200:
            tim.color(random_color())
            tim.forward(choice(range(50)))
            tim.setheading(choice(range(360)))
        else:
            tim.goto(0, 0)
    else:
        tim.setheading(0)
```

And it will work.

Another (better) way of doing it is to use an event to move the turtle. In the variation below, I used the `screen.ontimer` method to call the `move` function after a given time. After every call of `move`, it reschedules itself to run after some time (in the example 50 ms). In this way, you always have an event loop running and receiving the keyboard events.

```py
from turtle import Turtle, colormode, Screen
from random import choice, randint

colormode(255)
tim = Turtle('circle')
tim.speed('fastest')
tim.width(10)
screen = Screen()
go = True  # Boolean to initialize line 31


def pause():  # Currently it pauses, but doesn't resume.
    """Pause the program by setting go to False, and resume it if it was paused"""
    global go
    if go:
        go = False
    else:
        go = True


def random_color():
    """Return a random color"""
    r = randint(0, 255)
    g = randint(0, 255)
    b = randint(0, 255)
    generated_color = (r, g, b)
    return generated_color

def move():
    if go:  # As default is True, after pausing can't restart it...
        if 200 > tim.xcor() > -200 and 200 > tim.ycor() > -200:
            tim.color(random_color())
            tim.forward(choice(range(50)))
            tim.setheading(choice(range(360)))
        else:
            tim.goto(0, 0)
    screen.ontimer(fun=move, t=50)   # Move every 0.05 s

screen.listen()  # Starts listening for events
screen.onkey(fun=pause, key='p')  # Event - when the 'p' key is pressed, the 'pause' function is called.
screen.ontimer(fun=move, t=0)   # Schedule the first movement
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good catch.  I tried adding code to the main body of the loop to trace the program flow, but even that didn't enable a resume attempt.

Comment: Cool solutions. Learned how both work and will implement it in the future.
Thanks a lot